# flutter Insert pictures from the previous page

Tags: ios, flutter, dart

```
class AddResultPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const AddResultPage({
    Key? key, 
    required this.faceImage, 
    required this.faceName,
    }) : super(key: key);

  final File? faceImage;
  final String faceName;

  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          faceImage == null ? Container() : Image.file(faceImage!),
          // ignore: prefer_const_constructors
          CircleAvatar(
            radius: 50,
            foregroundImage: ,
          ),
          Text(faceName),
```

how insert image in CircleAvatar?
i don't know why it is wrong.......

```
foregroundImage: faceImage,
```

i don't know how to use CircleAvatar, file path....

please help....

Answer (score 0):

You can't insert a file as an Image,  what you can do though is to use

```
FileImageCircleAvatar(
    ..
    foregroundImage: FileImage(widget.faceImage),
),
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to assign the file into the `foregroundImage` which expects an Image Provider. Since you are trying to display the image from file, you should use `FileImage(imageFIle)`

```html
CircleAvatar(
   radius: 50,
   foregroundImage: FileImage(faceImage),     
   backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it!!

```
const SizedBox(height: bigSpace),
                Center(
                  child: CircleAvatar(
                  radius: 80,
                  foregroundImage: FileImage(faceImage!)
                  //faceImage == null ? Container() : Image.file(faceImage!),
                ),
              ),
```